# Save the optimization results from PyGMO by using pickle or dill

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I generated a population [using PyGMO](http://esa.github.io/pygmo/documentation/population.html). A population is a class which contains the individual results of the computation. I can iterate through the population and save the current function values and the parameter values. Unfortunately I cannot dump the whole class e.g. using pickle or dill. If I try:

```
with open('pop', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(pop,f)
```

I do get:

```
RuntimeError: unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported
```

It would be great to serialize the whole object because I might be able to use it for a warm start.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, I had the same issue some days ago. Instead of saving the whole population, save the whole class (island or archipelago). I did use cPickle and pickle, and they both work fine.

The trick to declare the class of your problem before dumping or loading the object. You can see more [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/pickleproblem).

Regards!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry... nooob posting, ill fix it in a while